# Multiple Document Roots based on directory?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, configuration, directory, document-root

My server's structure is like this:

```
|- var
   |-- www
       |--- website1
       |--- website2
       |--- website3
```

I'm currently working on `website1`, but I found that when I submit one of my Ajax forms, it returns the following error:

```
http://www.website.com/signup: The requested URL /signup was not found on this server.
```

When it should be looking under `http://www.website.com/website1/signup` instead.

Here's what I currently have added in my `apache2.conf`:

```
Alias /website1 "/var/www/website1/public"
<Directory /var/www/website1>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And my `DocumentRoot` is set to `/var/www` in my VirtualHosts. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This can't work. You confuse the `Alias` directive with a `Virtual Host`.

What you call `www.website1.com` is a hostname, not a directory part of the url. Therefore the Alias directive will not catch. An Alias directive allows you to map something like http://www.website.com/folder1 to an arbitrary location inside your local file system by means of a directive like `Alias /folder1 ...`. Not more. It does not see the requested host, since it is located *inside* a host configuration.

Instead you need a Virtual Host for each hostname / domain name you want to serve content for. If you have no virtual hosts setup yet, then the http server will fall back to the default host, which is what you call `www.website.com`. 
All options of the apache http server are documented in excellent quality. I suggest you take a look into that documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

---

To be precise here: what you describe *can* actually be done by means of url rewriting. But it would be a pain and very intransparent. Virtual hosts are the way to go.

Comment: How can I modify my VirtualHost to make this work then?

Comment: Well, inside the configuration of your http server. I suggest you take a look at the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Apache's Virtual Hosts.

In your Apache config:

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.example.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example2
ServerName www.example.org

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```